# Structure of Java web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, svn, web-applications

Sorry to ask this simple question.I have searched a lot and I can't find a reliable answer that exactly what I want. That's why I created this question.

we completed two spring projects in Java.

Each project , we have created , has a different folder structure in `WebContent` for module separation.

Now we are going to start a new project using eclipse with SVN and the project has three modules.

**WebContent Folder structure for Project one is** ,

```
WebContent

    - moduleOne
        - conf
            - moduleOne.conf
        - css
            - moduleOne.css
        - js
            - moduleOne.js
        - jsp
            - moduleOne.jsp
        - images
            - moduleOne.png

    - moduleTwo
        - conf
            - moduleTwo.conf
        - css
            - moduleTwo.css
        - js
            - moduleTwo.js
        - jsp
            - moduleTwo.jsp
        - images
            - moduleTwo.png

    - META-INF

    - WEB-INF
        - lib
        - web.xml
```

**WebContent Folder structure for Project one is ,**

```
WebContent

    - conf
        - moduleOne
            - moduleOne.conf
        - moduleTwo
            - moduleTwo.conf

    - css
        - moduleOne
            - moduleOne.css
        - moduleTwo
            - moduleTwo.css

    - images        
        - moduleOne
            - moduleOne.png
        - moduleTwo
            - moduleTwo.png

    - js
        - moduleOne
            - moduleOne.js
        - moduleTwo
            - moduleTwo.js

    - jsp       
        - moduleOne
            - moduleOne.jsp
        - moduleTwo
            - moduleTwo.jsp



    - META-INF

    - WEB-INF
        - lib
        - web.xml
```

Now we are in a situation to choose the preferred way of creating a folder structure.

Also it should be:

1. Easily customizable.
2. Easy to modify a separate module,if any new requirement came.

Any new ideas or methods and all answers would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i suggest the first one. easy to understand and soon new employees can understand the structure by just one sight.

Comment: Consider putting your .jsp files underneath WEB-INF. It's generally considered safer, as it ensures that they cannot be loaded directly via a URL.

Comment: @Steve can you please draw the folder structure which should be very useful . Because I can have upto **10 - 15 JSP's** for every module.

Comment: But why 3 modules not eg. 2 ? or 4 ?

Comment: @Mr-Phi any number of modules in future. But currently we have only 3 modules in our product.

Comment: +1 on solution no. 1, who gives more ? ;-)

Comment: Please don't use code backticks (\`) to highlight words throughout your question. Only use this for inline code samples.

Comment: @Mr-Phi  what you think about the STEVE comment ?

Comment: I have knocked up an example folder structure in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep static web resources under a 'resources' directory and all views and config underneath WEB-INF. This ensures that I can enable liberal access permissions and caching on 'resources'. Also, this ensures that .jsp files will not be directly accessible via a URL (unless you mess up your config!). Other than that, your first solution above is solid. Especially, as it becomes easier to apply module-level security and other configuration based on the path to the relevant module.

So as a tweak to solution 1, I would recommend something like:

```
- resources
    - moduleOne
        - css
            - moduleOne.css
        - js
            - moduleOne.js
        - images
            - moduleOne.png
    - moduleTwo
        - css
            - moduleTwo.css
        - js
            - moduleTwo.js
        - images
            - moduleTwo.png
- META-INF
- WEB-INF
    - modules
        - moduleOne
            - conf
                - moduleOne.conf
            - views
                - moduleOneViewOne.jsp
        - moduleTwo
            - conf
                - moduleTwo.conf
            - views
                - moduleTwoViewOne.jsp
    - lib
    - web.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also why you put the conf in web-inf ?

Comment: I assumed that the conf files should not be visible to users of the web application. Maybe that's not the case?

Comment: Where are the .java files?

Comment: In a typical Maven War project structure, the above would be in `src/main/webapp`, whereas Java sources would be in `src/main/java`. In the final package, the Java sources would be compiled to `.class` files in `WEB-INF/classes` or (preferred) Jar files in `WEB-INF/lib`. Maven or Gradle will do that for you.