# Where should we store database config files in Java Eclipse Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I'm new in Java development and learning the basics of Eclipse environment.

Referring to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237568/structure-of-java-web-application), I got to know the folder structure of any web application (Dynamic Web Project).

I need to know the location of JDBC database configuration files having connection string, username, passwords etc.

**Question**: Should we keep the database configuration files (DAL) in WEB-INF and gain access from outside (I don't know how to do that) or should we keep the configuration files in src/package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC database configuration files must be done in the Dao class ... which is a simple java class we dont keep the database config files in web-inf... WEB_INF is not used for this.. u must read some docs first about that...

If you use hibernate for the database.. then the configuration file is `hibernate.cfg.xml` which is placed in `src/ Main/resources`

[image]

and if you are using jpa(java persistence api) then 
The `persistence.xml` file which contains the configurations of database is typically present in the src/META-INF directory of the persistence (JPA) project.

Comment: Ok, it means that I should create a package for database class, then import the java file wherever required. Also, I'm using Oracle 12c as database.

Comment: Yes right create a package and then a class.. and u can use any database just use right credentials for it

Comment: though it's not completely based on my project, still it helped :)